# Form validation not working on jquery steps before ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Form validation is  not working before ajax submit.Why is this code working?Can someone help me.I here by adding html code and ajax jquery steps.

```
<form id="business_form">
<div class="cfield"><input type="text" placeholder="" name="businessName" id="businessName" required/>
 </div>
</form>
```

jquery steps..

```
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_assets/assets/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_assets/assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  onStepChanged: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
  if(currentIndex==1)
  {
  var business_form = document.getElementById('business_form');
  var formData = new FormData(business_form); 
  $("#business_form").validate();
   $.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../business_save",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
          success: function (data) {
           },
          error: function () {
             alert("something went wrong");
             return false; 
           }
          });
       }

    });

    }
```

Please help

Comment: *"is not working"* is not a useful problem description. Please review the help section about how to write a good question and edit to elaborate exactly what the problem is, your troubleshooting steps, any console errors, etc.

Comment: I think your whole problem could be because you're including the jQuery Validate plugin *before* the jQuery library.  You must include the jQuery library first, then any jQuery plugins next.

Comment: Including a jQuery plugin before the jQuery library should have triggered a bunch of JS errors that you would have seen in the console.  Are you checking the console?